# DRF: Parent-Child Relationship Serialization to Dictionary instead of List when using unique_together

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm relatively new to using Django and Django Rest Framework, but here's what I'm trying to do.

I have two models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    name = models.CharField()
    age = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('parent', 'name',)
```

I want to serialize parent such that a GET on a parent returns something of the form:

```
{
    name: <parent name>,
    children: {
        <child name 1>: <age>,
        <child name 2>: <age>
    }
}
```

Currently, I can only figure out how to return a list of the children by using a serializer such as:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    children = ChildrenSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = '__all__'
```

Which returns:

```
{
    name: <parent name>,
    children: [
        {
            name: <child name 1>,
            age: <child age 1>
        },
        {
            name: <child name 2>,
            age: <child age 2>
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get the parent serializer to return a single dictionary under 'children' keyed by the child's name instead of a list of dictionaries?

Comment: You should probably mark slider's answer as correct accepted - just had the exact same problem as you and his solution solved it for me

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to get the `children` for a parent and build that dictionary yourself:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    children = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_children(self, obj):
        return {c.name: c.age for c in obj.child_set.all()}

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = '__all__'
```